# PHP Error Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0
>   Filename: controllers/basecontroller.php
>   Line Number: 616 and Line Number: 617

This is my code:

```
//Controller File
function _send_email($email_template, $receiver=array(), $data=array(), $sender=array()){
$this->load->model('ad_model');
$tmpl = $this->ad_model->getAdByCode($email_template);
$title = $tmpl['desc']; // Line 616
$html = $tmpl['html']; // Line 617
$html = str_replace("[NAME]", $receiver['name'] ,$html);
//$html = str_replace("[PWD]", $pwd ,$html);
$html = str_replace("[EMAIL]", $receiver['email'] ,$html);

foreach($data as $code=>$d){
  $html = str_replace("[".strtoupper($code)."]", $d ,$html);
}
...

//Model File
function getAdByCode($code){
    $this->db->select('html,desc');
    $rec = $this->db->get_where('ad', array('code'=>$code), 1,0);
    //echo $code;
    //echo print_r($rec,1);
    $rec = $rec->result_array();
  if(isset($rec[0])){
    $rec = $rec[0];
  } else {
    $rec = '';
  }     

    return $rec;
  }
}
```

Anyone would help?

Comment: how should we guess which are the named lines 616 & 617 ?

Comment: @OlegDubas the OP commented the lines in the code -> `$title = $tmpl['desc']; // Line 616     $html = $tmpl['html']; // Line 617`

Comment: The entries `'desc'` and `'html'` don't exist in `$tmpl`.

Comment: `Uninitialized string offset` typically means that you are trying to get an array key, when the var is a string, not an array. do a `var_dump($tmpl)` to check.

Comment: print_r($tmpl); and see what you get?

Comment: `var_dump($tmpl)` to find if its an array

Comment: I tried `var_dump($tmpl)` and got string(0) "".
The code above is for sending email, but now the recipients get blank email without content.

Answer (score 0):

seems both index not found in `$tmpl` array. try to make a check for values set or not to avoid notices

```
$title = (isset($tmpl['desc']) ? $tmpl['desc'] : ''); // Line 616
$html = (isset($tmpl['html']) ? $tmpl['html'] : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template array `$tmpl` does not contain `html` as key.

If you have control of it in  `$this->ad_model->getAdByCode($email_template);` you can change to use as confidence as you write here as `$tmpl['html']`.

But the suggested way of accessing a key element from an array is by checking its existance, like:

```
$title = isset($tmpl['desc']) ? $tmpl['desc'] : ''; 
$html = isset($tmpl['html']) ? $tmpl['html'] : '';
```